# How to run easy_install in cygwin?

Tags: python, cygwin, easy-install

I am trying to install some package in cygwin's python, but I'm getting the following error: "easy_install: command not found".

I have tried to run "easy_install.py", the result is also "easy_install.py: command not found". I have tried to search the whole of cygwin's /usr tree for anything named with the prefix "easy", none found.

Am I missing something? AFAIK, easy_install tool should be batteries included in python 2.5. Or is there a package that needs to be installed for that that I missed?

Answer (score 39):

From cygwin prompt, do:

```
$ wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
$ python ez_setup.py
```

This will install easy_install on your cygwin.

Easy as py.

Comment: Plus One for the Horrible Pun.

Comment: After installation, to use `easy_install`, make sure C:\Python27\Scripts (or similar) is in your PATH.

Answer (score 18):

`easy_install` is part of the setuptools package. This package is provided by cygwin. To install it, rerun the cygwin *setup[...].exe* installer, and at the package selection step, tick "Python/python-setuptools".

The easy_install script has the version number attached.  Instead of running `easy_install`, run `easy_install-2.7` or `easy_install-3.4` (or whatever `x.y` version of Python you have installed).

Comment: Install the cygwin package, then run `easy_install-`<ver>.  Turns out the cygwin packages suffix with the version number in case you have python 2 and python 3 installed.

Comment: To be precise: In the setup window view 'Full' and in the Search window type `python2-setuptools` or `python3-setuptools`.

Answer (score 4):

Easy Install is a python module (easy_install) bundled with setuptools, which can be found here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools . You must install setuptools by yourself.

- If you want to install it into windows python than use **setuptools install script** from **cmd** shell or use MS Windows installer
- If you need python with setuptools to work within cygwin than:

  - use cygwin's own python (you can install one using cygwin's setup.exe)
  - use setuptools source

Comment: I don't think so. "which easy_setup" and "which easy_setup.py" says that it is not found.

Comment: The [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools) page mentioned above even has a [specific section with detailed instructions for installing setuptools (including easy_install) on Cygwin](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#cygwin-mac-os-x-linux-other).

Comment: There is (at least now) a setuptools package in Cygwin which is almost certainly a better way to install it for a Cygwin installation - and easier for someone used to Cygwin.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to installing setuptools (as described in other answers), you also need to make sure `C:\Python25\Scripts` is in your `PATH`.

Comment: Are you sure? I use the python that comes with cygwin and not the separatly installed windows one.